# Classes.jsa file not deleting through C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, jsa

I have a file named "Classes.jsa" in my application. I need to delete this file through C# code. Manually i can delete this file. But not able to delete it through coding. I tried to delete in Admin mode. But showing the error like

```
Access to the path denied "F:\MyApp\Classes.jsa"
```

MyCode:

```
sting fileName=@"F:\MyApp\Classes.jsa";
if(file.exists(fileName))
{
   File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

Anyone can resolve this issue?

Thanks and Regards,
Kathiresan S.

Comment: Do you have the file in place? If yes, What happens? any exception?

Comment: Yes. The file is present in the location. While deleting, it raising an exception as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this.

The below code working for me:

**Code**:

```
sting fileName=@"F:\MyApp\Classes.jsa";
FileInfo file=new FileInfo(fileName);

if(file.exists(fileName))
{
   file.IsReadOnly=false;
   File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify code from Kathir Subramaniam. I check my machine and it works

```
    [Test]
    public void FileDelete()
    {
        string fileName = @"D:\FileDelete\Classes.jsa";
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            file.IsReadOnly = false;
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
    }
```